# Understanding a multilayer perceptron network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to understand how to train a multilayer; however, I'm having some trouble figuring out how to determine a suitable network architecture--i.e., number of nodes/neurons in each layer of the network.

For a specific task, I have four input sources that can each input one of three states. I guess that would mean four input neurons firing either 0, 1 or 2, but as far as I'm told, input should be kept binary?

Furthermore am I having some issues choosing on the amount of neurons in the hidden layer. Any comments would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Determining an acceptable Network structure for a multi-layer perceptron is actually straightforward.

1. **Input Layer**: How many features/dimensions are in
   your data--ie, how many columns in
   each data row. Add one to this (for
   the bias node) and that is the
   number of nodes for the first (input
   layer).
2. **Output Layer**: Is your MLP running in 'machine'
   mode or 'regression' mode
   ('regression' used here in the
   machine learning rather than the
   statistical sense)--ie, does my MLP
   return a class label or a predicted
   value? If the latter, then your
   output layer has a single node. If
   the former, then your output layer
   has the same number of nodes as
   class labels. For instance, if the
   result you want is to label each
   instance as either "fraud", or "not
   fraud", that's two class labels,
   therefore, two nodes in your output
   layer.
3. **Hidden Layer(s)**: In between these two (input and
   output) are obviously the hidden
   layers. Always start with a single
   hidden layer. So H\how many nodes? Here's a rule of thumb: set the (initial) size of the hidden layer to some number of nodes just slightly greater than the number of nodes in the input layer. Compared with having fewer nodes than the input layer, this excess capacity will help your numerical optimization routine (eg, gradient descent) converge.

In sum, begin with three layers for your network architecture; the sizes of the first (input) and last (output are fixed by your data, and by your model design, respectively. A hidden layer just slightly larger than the input layer is nearly always a good design to begin.

So in your case, a suitable network structure to begin would be:

*input layer*: 5 nodes --> *hidden layer*: 7 nodes --> *output layer*: 3 nodes

Comment: Thank you, Doug. Your answer was very thorough and helpful. Its fascinating how books and professors can make problems appear so advanced, when the answer really is very (as you put it) straight forward.

Comment: your p. 3 is seriously wrong, e.g. if you have 3 input nodes and 5 output nodes, your rule suggests that there "obviously" can't be any nodes in hidden layer as there is no 3 <= x => 5;
this paper also states that some authors fall to this mistake: [Warren S. Sarle NN FAQ](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ3.html#A_hu)

Answer (score 10):

I disagree with doug's answer above on a few points.

You have 4 discrete (3 way categorical) inputs. You should (unless you have a strong reason not to) represent that as 12 binary inputs using a 1-of-3 encoding for each of your four conceptual inputs.
So if you input is [2,0,1,1] then your network should be given:
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
If your network implementation requires a manual bias, then you should add another always on bit for the bias, but most sensible neural net implementations don't require that.

Try a few different numbers of hidden units. You don't need to restrict yourself to a hidden layer size smaller than the input layer size, but if you make it larger you should be careful to regularlize your weights, perhaps with L2 or L1 weight decay and maybe even also doing early-stopping in training (stop training when your error on a held out validation set stops improving).

Comment: I wholeheartedly second this opinion. The doug answer simplifies the problem too much; without this output representation, non-trivial tasks would fail. Also, remember to use a softmax function if your variables can only be in one state at a time.